# How to set the context for getContentResolver()?

Tags: android, sqlite, android-context

I have created `query()` method inside 2 different classes `A` and `B` in 2 different files where `A` and `B` are querying from different tables:

```
public Cursor query(Uri uri, String[] projection, String selection,
            String[] selectionArgs, String sortOrder) { 
}
```

Then from 2 different `Activity` I tried to call using following code:

```
Cursor cursor = getContentResolver().query(uri, projection, null, null, null);
```

But from both `Activity` it's calling only `query()` method from `Class A`. Do I missing to set something before call the `getContentResolver()`?

My manifest:

```
<manifest>
    <application>
......................
        <provider
            android:name=".provider.ItemProvider"
            android:authorities="com.waveletandroid.provider" >
        </provider>
       <provider
            android:name=".provider.CustomerProvider"
            android:authorities="com.waveletandroid.provider" >
        </provider>
    </application>
</manifest>
```

My `URI` in `ItemListActivity`:

```
itemUri = Uri.parse("content://com.waveletandroid.provider/waveletandroid";
```

My `URI` in `CustomerListActivity`:

```
customerUri = Uri.parse("content://com.waveletandroid.provider/waveletandroid";
```

Comment: that depends on your uri and the definition of your contentprovider

Comment: Please let me know how I can set which contentprovider I want to use in activity.

Comment: that depends on the uri and the uri matcher. post your uri and your manifest

Comment: HI, I have added the manifest and uri but meanwhile the problem has been solved from another post. Actually same authorities can't be added in 2 provider. So I have changed the authority of 2nd one. Now it's working fine.

Comment: how exactly did you expect android to know which provider to choose if both have the same authority ?

Comment: you may or may not have noticed, but both uri are identical. u in uri stands for universal (relatively, of course), which can be understood as "not context dependent", which can be understood as "2 identical uri point to the same element"

Comment: yes bro. I have started Android programming last week.

Comment: Yes right. I haven't noticed it before. But now it's clear to me. Another question I have added [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15004880/is-it-good-practice-to-use-contentprovider-to-handle-database-operations). Please try to answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try out as below:

> ```
> public Cursor getAllContacts() {
>        return database.query("country", new String[] {"_id", "name"},
>         null, null, null, null, "name");
>    }
> ```

In your activity access this method as below:

> ```
>  Cursor cursor =getAllContacts();
> ```

Comment: Your answer is also working. thanks. Also solved using another way mentioned in above comment.