# Is it good practice to use ContentProvider to handle database operations?

Tags: android, android-sqlite

First let you know I am new in Android.

1. Is it good practice to use ContentProvider to handle database table operations only for one application?
2. Trying to create multiple classes to handle database table operations. Created a database helper as follow:

   public class WSDatabaseHelper extends SQLiteOpenHelper {

   ```
       private static final String DATABASE_NAME = "wsemp";
       private static final int DATABASE_VERSION = 5;

       public WSDatabaseHelper(Context context) {
           super(context, DATABASE_NAME, null, DATABASE_VERSION);
       }

       @Override
       public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase database) {
           ItemTable.onCreate(database);
           CustomerTable.onCreate(database);
       }

       @Override
   public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase database, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {
           ItemTable.onUpgrade(database, oldVersion, newVersion);
           CustomerTable.onUpgrade(database, oldVersion, newVersion);
       }
   }
   ```

Created a class to handle database table operation:

```
public class CustomerBean {
    private WSDatabaseHelper database;

    @Override
    public boolean onCreate() {
        database = new WSDatabaseHelper(getContext());
        return false;
    }

public boolean insertObject(valObj) {
    SQLiteDatabase db = database.getWritableDatabase();
    db.insert(CustomerTable.TABLE_CUST_ACCOUNT_INDEX, null, values);
    }
}
```

But now I am not sure how I can call this insertObject function from my activity or session file. I tried by CustomerBean.isnertObject(obj) but it's asking to change the method to static.

Comment: i do'nt understand what you are trying to do. what is customerbean in regard to customertable ? why the @Override when nothing is overriden ? what tutorial have you followed ?

Comment: I have used this tutorial [vogella](http://www.vogella.com/articles/AndroidSQLite/article.html). CustomerTable contains only the create table statement and static names of the table fields. Forget the CustomerTable and @override. Only please let me know how I can call the insertObject() method of CustomerBean class from Activity?

Comment: i don't understand what prevents you from calling it directly ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Is it good practice to use ContentProvider to handle database table operations only for one application?

If your data is exclusive only for your application and other application cannot use it I don't see any reason to use ContentProviders. ContentProvider is used as an interface for sharing your application's data to other application. If your data can be shared or other application is dependent on it then you have to use ContentProvider.

Also you can create set of permissions to your content providers to restrict some operations in the provider.

Comment: If the data absolutely must be private, then there wouldn't be any benefit to using a ContentProvider. It adds a layer of abstraction on how data is handled in the background, but that can be achieved with your own class.

Comment: I think you may find that, even if your data is entirely private, it is more convenient to wrap it in a CP.  A great example is how much easier it is to use a SimpleCursorLoader than it is to create your own working subclass of AsyncTaskLoader.